# Zend, URL routing, 404 urls with unidentified or unknown parameters

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

I a large number of routes in zend with various parameters. I need to throw a 404 if the url has
 1. invalid params
 2. unknown params

for instance, I have the following url

```
http://www.example.com/something/1
```

with route

```
'client'    => array(
    'type'          => 'Zend_Controller_Router_Route',
    'route'         => '/:alias/:page',
    'defaults'      => array('module' => 'client', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'details', 'alias' => false, 'page' => 1),
),
```

I need to throw 404 when the request url has unknown - extra stuff, like

```
http://www.example.com/something/1/whatever/can/be/added
```

Is there some convenient way of achieving this?

Comment: Could you post the full route configuration, as normally this already happens whenever a route has more parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.

The way Zend Router works is if your route is /something/1/another/param/is/here

then obviously in your action then the param "alias" will be 'something' and "page" will be '1'.

But Zend Router will also map these additional params for you, so $this->_getParam("another") will return "param" and $this->_getParam("is") will return "here".

To disable this and throw a 404 you would have to overwrite Zend Router with your own adaption, and throw a 404 if these additional parameters are found.